# Can we use multithreading concept along with WatchService API in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, watchservice

Suppose I have a directory in which I'll get multiple incoming files into that directory.I need to process all the files based on the file created time i.e, first created file need to be processed first.

In order to watch the directory, I had implemented WatchService API.

How can we sort the files in a directory based on the created date? And can we implement multithreading concept over here ?

Comment: Multi-threading is certainly possible. Say `File1` gets created, then shortly after `File2`, do you care whether `File2` finishes processing before `File1`? (perhaps `File2` is much smaller or something)

Comment: No, I don't care about the processing time of File2. Can you please edit the sample code over here.

Comment: @Michael, I have a similar concept, I looked at your solution and wanted to know where the WatchService API fits into your solution?. I am already using the watch service which works perfect in processing the first file, but the program exits upon reading the next even though detect

Answer (score 0):

Just a skeleton really but it should get your started. It will compile but it won't do anything.

When you see a new file come in, add it to the end of the queue. There are 4 threads created with the executor service waiting to process files. Once one of them comes in, one thread will pick it up and start processing. If they're all busy, the next files will have to wait but will still be processed in the order they came in.

I'm not sure whether the sleep is a good idea or not. I suppose it depends how often you will have files coming in.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class FileWatcher //implements WatchService
{
    private class FileProcessor implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                try
                {
                    File file = fileQueue.take(); // blocks
                    process(file);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                // maybe sleep for a bit here (exponential backoff?)
            }
        }

        private void process(File file)
        {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 4;
    private static final int QUEUE_SIZE  = 1000;

    private final BlockingQueue<File> fileQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_SIZE);

    public FileWatcher()
    {
        // Create our 4 processors
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            executorService.execute(new FileProcessor());
        }
    }

    // When a file comes in to your WatchService
    private void onNewFile(File file)
    {
        fileQueue.add(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dev777 May I ask if this resolution helped you? I am struggling with a similar concept and cant seem to find the right help on it, I have been stuck on this for days